# Extract sub-arrays of consecutive numbers that meet condition

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following input array:

```
a = np.array([np.nan, 10, 5, 7, np.nan, np.nan, 1, 2, 3, np.nan])
```

I want to extract subarrays of consecutive numbers splitting them up whenever there is a `nan` value.

```
res = [[10, 5, 7], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: You might be able to do something with `np.split()`, where the second argument is an array of the indexes of the `nan`s.

Answer (score 0):

A solution based on `scipy.ndimage.label`:

```py
import scipy.ndimage

def find_valid_subarrays(a):
    a = np.array(a)
    label, num_features = scipy.ndimage.label(~np.isnan(a))
    return [a[label == feature] for feature in range(1, num_features+1)]
```

What it does:

```py
In [1]: a = np.array([np.nan, 10,  5,  7, np.nan, np.nan,  1,  2,  3, np.nan])

In [2]: find_valid_subarrays(a)

Out[2]: [array([10.,  5.,  7.]), array([1., 2., 3.])]
```

I am hoping for something more readable.

Answer (score 0):

A one-line solution that requires no further dependencies would be

```py
res = [[int(a_elem) for a_elem in list(a[ind])] for ind in np.ma.clump_unmasked(np.ma.masked_invalid(a))]
```

yielding

```py
res
>[[10, 5, 7], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Note that an explicit type conversion back to `int` is performed within the list comprehension. If this is not relevant for your use case, run

```
[list(a[ind]) for ind in np.ma.clump_unmasked(np.ma.masked_invalid(a))]
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using a utility I made for finding runs of consecutive values in a mask, [`haggis.npy_util.mask2runs`](https://haggis.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#haggis.npy_util.mask2runs) combined with [`np.isnan`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html), you can do

```
runs = haggis.npy_util.mask2runs(~np.isnan(a))
result = [a[slice(*x)] for x in runs]
```

The same effect can be produced with pure numpy, using a simplified version of the `mask2runs` function. Something like this:

```
runs = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(np.r_[False, ~np.isnan(a), False])).reshape(-1, 2)
result = [a[slice(*x)] for x in runs]
```